# MY button it doesn't hid

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I have an if statement that value come from server, I receive the correct value from server according that bool value, I hide the button or not.

The problem is with breakpoint I can see that clearly the code pass from my code but the problem is the button doesnt show.

here is the button:
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *threewayscall;

and in .m file I have the if statment

```
@implementation KeypadEditorView {


    BOOL initialized;
    BOOL layoutInitialized;

    CGFloat minimumHeaderHeight;
    CGSize naturalKeypadSize;
}

@synthesize threewayscall;




-(void)dealloc
{
    [_repeatTimer invalidate];

    _headerView = nil;
    _numberLabel = nil;
    _keypadView = nil;
    _backspaceButton = nil;
   _enterButton = nil;
   _number = nil;
    threewayscall = nil ;
    _keypadImplementation = nil;
    _repeatTimer = nil;
}

#pragma mark Internal methods

-(void)delayedInit
{
    if (initialized) {
        return;
    }


    if (support_three_ways_call){
        threewayscall.hidden = NO;

    } else {

        threewayscall.hidden = YES;
    }


}
```

the problem is it doesn't show the button if I make both yes, it shows or both no it hide but when I receive the correct value, even it need to hide, it doesn't hide.

Comment: Do you call `delayedInit` on the main thread?

Comment: Hi @schmidt9, Yes.

Comment: Is `support_three_ways_call` really set to YES (supposed it is a bool)? Put log calls in if/else clause and see without setting breakpoint

Comment: try setting it like this : `threewayscall.hidden = !support_three_ways_call;`

Comment: Did you connect `threewayscall` in IB? (I always forget).

Comment: Hi @Willeke, YES It connected to IB and it boo, value